# How to create a REST API that is user generated and moderated?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, api, rest

I have a few nutritional diet tracking mobile apps built with react-native and firebase. They currently use a few nutritional APIs to be able to pull in data for foods that users can add to their diet logs (ie calories, carbs, proteins, fats, nutrients, etc).

https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiref2&method=foods.search 
https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs 
https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api

My issue is that these APIs lack data that my users want. However, lots of times other users have the actual data and could easily upload it to some database so the other users could use it as well.

How can I create my own API similar to the ones above so that users can upload their data and even self-moderate it among themselves? I was thinking it could somehow be done with the firebase database, but I am not sure how to go about it or if its the best route. All the "create an api" google searching has not really helped me with where to start.

Comment: Search for firebase function. more specific search for using express js in firebase function.

Comment: You are in a very good way. With Firebase you won't create an API from the scratch. Based on your use case I think you will need Firestore and Firebase Authentication. Here are some resources about how to start the mission: https://firebase.google.com/docs?hl=pt-br&gclid=CjwKCAjw3K2XBhAzEiwAmmgrAvEaJ3DgUQDeY1Po9HwPwCJ9dCO77z3wCALJN8d98lYNjlhLu-KYKRoCNCwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352

Comment: I already use firebase functions, firestore, and authentication for features inside the app. I am just unsure if that is the best way to also create the API which would hold 10000s of nutritional food item data